# Assigning a sequence number for an existing table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to insert a sequence number as a new column into the existing table. Can you give a better solution.

Comment: Every table has its own Object ID which is accessible from `user_tables` view. If you want to add a column to your table that contains values in sequential order, use sequences. Read more about sequences on Oracle Docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm

Comment: Ok, Is it possible to insert in one statement.. Instead of defining "sequence_name.nextval" for every row.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the new column, update it using ...

```
 update my_table set my_new_column = rownum
```

... and then create a sequence starting with (the maximum number you just inserted plus one) to continue for new rows.

Comment: Thank you so much... I got what I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sample table:

```
create table foo (some_data varchar(20));
insert into foo (some_data) values ('foo');
insert into foo (some_data) values ('bar');
insert into foo (some_data) values ('foobar');
insert into foo (some_data) values ('barfoo');
commit;
```

Add a new column:

```
alter table foo add (id integer);
```

Now create a new sequence to populate the `id` column:

```
create sequence foo_seq;
```

Update the new column using the sequence:

```
update foo set id = foo_seq.nextval;
```